# How to apply both- setDate and (minDate and maxDate )Date Range dynamically using jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a drop-down from where I select the year and the other calendar field which has the datepicker.

What I want to do is if I select the year 2021, the default date should be 12/31/2021 and it should also be the maxDate.

After that, if I change the year 2022, the default date should be 12/31/2022, and just like previously it should also be the maxDate.

I have gone through many StackOverflow questions and the [api](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) , but didn't solve the problem.  What am I missing or doing wrong ?

```
function updateCalendarDate() {
     var calMaxDate = new Date(12 + "/" + 31 + "/" + $("#year").val());
     $('#calDate').val(beforeShowDay1(calMaxDate));
     $("#calDate").datepicker({
         "startDate": beforeShowDay(new Date()),
         "endDate": beforeShowDay(calMaxDate),
         "minDate": beforeShowDay(new Date()),
         "maxDate": beforeShowDay(calMaxDate)
     });
     $("#calDate").datepicker("destroy");
     $("#calDate").datepicker("setDate", beforeShowDay(calMaxDate));
     $( "#calDate" ).datepicker("refresh");
};
```

what I have tried so far is: 
1.

```
 $("#calDate").datepicker({
    "setDate": beforeShowDay(calMaxDate),
     "startDate": beforeShowDay(new Date()),
     "endDate": beforeShowDay(calMaxDate),
     "minDate": beforeShowDay(new Date()),
     "maxDate": beforeShowDay(calMaxDate)
 });
```

2. Set the default date first and then destroy and set the maxDate again

`$("#calDate").datepicker("setDate", beforeShowDay(calMaxDate));`

`$('#calDate').datepicker('destroy');`
`$('#calDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(calMaxDate));`

If I use the `setDate` then, the `setDate` property doesn't work.

Comment: `new Date(12 + "/" + 31 + "/" + $("#year").val());` why not `new Date($("#year").val(),11,31)` so you don't have any localisation issues?

Comment: no localisation issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [api](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) you have the the flowing

to set date : use `setDate`

```
$("selector").datepicker("setDate", yourCreatedDate);
```

to set max Date use `maxDate`

```
$("selector").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", yourCreatedDate );
```

See below working snippet for more understanding

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#calDate").datepicker({
  });
  
  $('#year').on("change", function(e) {
    if(!this.value) return;
    
    let setDate = new Date (this.value,11,31);
    
    console.log(setDate);
    //this prevent maxdate if going ahead  for date
    $("#calDate").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", null );
    $("#calDate").datepicker("setDate", setDate);
    $("#calDate").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", setDate );
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import url("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/start/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<input id='year' type='number' />
<input id="calDate" />
```